# ASP.NET 4 catch status code xxx

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-status-codes

I want to catch, for example, 403 in my code.
I've got vs 2012 an created new solution WebApplication1 as ASP.NET Empty Web Application. I've added a Global.asax and then added an handler to all the Global's events (BeginRequest, EndRequest, Error and so on...) that contains a call to:

```
   private void CurrentStatusCode()
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.Response.StatusCode != 0)
            {
                int a; // breakpoint
            }    
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

I've set no default page so when I debug my application I get a 403. Well, sooner ol later i expected to get a 403 in the try section but every time an handler calls CurrentStatusCode() and Response is available StatusCode is always set to 200.

Where I have to check to find the 403?

**EDIT**
Yes, fiddler confirms that's a 403

@jbl : so at which level I will see it?

Comment: how is authorization handled in your environment ? If it is at the webserver level, you won't see it in your .net code.

Comment: Are you sure that you will get a 403?  Hook up Fiddler and watch.